# add Bundle field to a custom entity

Tags: entities

I am trying to add a new bundle field into my custom entity, I added the following code into the MyCustomEntity.php file, I uninstalled my module, so, I installed it again, the field is showing up on the view, but in my data base the field is not added.

Could you please support me?

```
$fields['new_name'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('text_long')
  ->setLabel(t('New Name'))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'text_textarea',
  ])
  ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
  ->setTargetBundle($bundle);
```

Thank you, I will really appreciate your support.

Answer (score 1):

For the Entity base field update, You'll need to also add an update hook to apply it

For example:

**Installing a new field storage definition**

```
use Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition;

/**
 * Implements hook_update_N
 */
function example_update_8701() {
  $bundle = 'article';
  $field_storage_definition = BaseFieldDefinition::create('text_long')
  ->setLabel(t('New Name'))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'text_textarea',
  ])->setRevisionable(TRUE)
  ->setTargetBundle($bundle);

  \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()
    ->installFieldStorageDefinition('new_name', 'node', 'EXAMPLE_MODULE', $field_storage_definition);
}
```

Documentation: https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742

Comment: it does not work for me

Comment: Make sure the bundle param matches, it should add a field to the article node type.

Comment: thank you! it works now